# How can i create my own SIGNAL and channel it to a SLOT?

Tags: python, qt, python-2.7, qt4, pyqt4

On a mouse click on the QLineEdit widget, I want to clear its content completely.

QLineEdit does not have a SIGNAL to detect mouse clicks, so I wrote the below class for installEventFilter.

But please suggest if I can channel this to SLOT("clear()").
Suggest where I am missing something-

```
class mouseclick(QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(mouseclick, self).__init__(parent)
    def eventFilter(self, object, event):
        if (event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonPress):
            self.emit(SIGNAL("aa"), "a")
        return False

class Form(QDialog):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(Form,self).__init__(parent)
        self.UsrName = QLineEdit("Username")
        self.filter = mouseclick()
        self.UsrName.installEventFilter(self.filter)
        self.connect(self.UsrName,SIGNAL("aa"), SLOT("clear()"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use event filter. You can achieve that with simple way:

```
self.UsrName = QLineEdit("username")
self.UsrName.mousePressEvent = lambda event: self.UsrName.clear()
```

That's it.
Every time the user clicks the lineEdit, it will be cleared.